# find command works locally but outputs nothing on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, terminal, sh

I wrote the below command to traverse the current directory deeply, ignoring everything in node_modules, and outputting all found *.bzl, *.sky, BUILD.bazel, BUILD, *.BUILD and WORKSPACE files.

```
find . -type f ! -path '*/node_modules/*' \( -name '*.bzl' -o -name '*.sky' -o -name BUILD.bazel -o -name BUILD -o -name '*.BUILD' -o -name WORKSPACE \)
```

I want to get a list of all such files and do some operations on them in a jenkins pipeline. I wrote the following in jenkins:

```
String files = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "find . -type f ! -path '*/node_modules/*' \\( -name '*.bzl' -o -name '*.sky' -o -name BUILD.bazel -o -name BUILD -o -name '*.BUILD' -o -name WORKSPACE \\)")

echo "${files}"
```

but the output in jenkins is:

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ find . -type f ! -path */node_modules/* ( -name *.bzl -o -name *.sky -o -name BUILD.bazel -o -name BUILD -o -name *.BUILD -o -name WORKSPACE ) 
[Pipeline] echo
```

Comment: i tried adding "-print" at the end and it didn't do anything either... I've spent way too much time troubleshooting this T_T

Comment: I figured it out ... works with triple single quotes

Answer (score 0):

looks like you forgot to make variables variables like this:

```
sh(returnStdout: true, script: "find . -type f ! -path '*/node_modules/*' \\( -name '*.bzl' -o -name '*.sky' -o -name ${BUILD}.bazel -o -name ${BUILD} -o -name '*.${BUILD}' -o -name ${WORKSPACE} \\)")
```